# How to switch between output window and code editor in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I tried google'ing around and I could not find the shortcut that can send me to the "output window(if that's what it's called)" after telling my program to compile and run. Also, how would I switch back to my code editor from that output window?

I've done it before, but I forgot it.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a little unclear what you really mean:

The Output pane is called the Console. It is displayed in the Debug area.

There are a few ways to get to it.

In the Toolbar Menu:

Use the Debug area toggle button.

[image]

From the Menu Bar : View Menu :-> Debug area :-> *Show the Debug area* menu
to open the **Debug** area set as it was last displayed

[image]

---

[image]

Note the shortcut for this:  <kbd>cmd</kbd> +  <kbd>shift</kbd> +   <kbd>Y</kbd>

Use View Menu :-> Debug area :-> Activate **Console** area to Show the **Debug** area with the **Console** showing.

[image]

---

[image]

---

Note the shortcut for this:  <kbd>cmd</kbd> +  <kbd>shift</kbd> +   <kbd>C</kbd>

Or just show the **Console** area if the debug area is already showing.

You can also use the **Debug** area show hide toggle to show/hide either the Variable View or the  Console area  view

---

[image]

Comment: Whoa thanks for doing all that. Cmd+Shift+c was the command I was looking for. It switches me into the active console while the program is running and waiting for my input. Now just wondering, if I wanted to edit my code, but I'm in the active console area, do you how to switch back?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Command+Shift+Y. It is a toggle shortcut which opens and closes output in Xcode.

Comment: Cmd+Shift+Y only opens or closes the Debug area.

Comment: @markhunte : I thought he only asking about the debug area ! . U explain it awesomely.